# How to calculate Quarterly Survival rate from Quarterly Probability of Default

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to calculate the Quarterly Marginal PD. I have calculated it as given in the below image but I am thinking about whether the Survival rate calculation is making sense or not.

My Question is When we have Quarterly PD, Is it correct to calculate the Survival rate as `(1-Quarterly PiT PD)^(1/4)` or Just `(1-Quarterly PiT PD)`. In this example, I have calculated the Survival Rate as `(1-Quarterly PiT PD)^(1/4)`

Additional Info: Quarterly Cumulative Data for the last row has been calculated as given in the excel formula in the last cell.

PiT PD for each quarter is derived from the below Vasicek model based on the constant TTC PD, Single macroeconomic Factor z(for each quarter value), and constant asset correlation rho

PiT PD = $\Phi \left( \frac{\phi^{-1}(PD_i)-\sqrt{\rho_i}z}{\sqrt{1-\rho_i}} \right)$

[image]

Comment: $S(t)=\exp(-\int^t_0 h(s)\,dx)$, time in years. $4(S(t+1/4)-S(t))=4S(t)\Big(\exp\big(-\int^{t+1/4}_t h(s)\,ds\big)-1\Big)$ would be the way to go. You can also use the mean value theorem to get an approximation using, say the value at $t$.

Comment: Since we use the Microsoft Excel model. please see the example, Is it correct to use the (1-Quarterly PiT PD)^(1/4) or (1-Quarterly PiT PD) for survival rate?

Comment: Since we use the Microsoft Excel model. please see the example, Is it correct to use the (1-Quarterly PiT PD)^(1/4) or (1-Quarterly PiT PD) for quarterly survival rate?